# How to extract value from Scala cats IO

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I need to get Array[Byte] value from ioArray which is IO[Array[Byte]] // IO is from cats library

```
  object MyTransactionInputApp extends App{

     val ioArray : IO[Array[Byte]] = generateKryoBinary()
  

     val i : Array[Byte] = ioArray.unsafeRunSync();

      println(i)

  def generateKryoBinaryIO(transaction: Transaction): IO[Array[Byte]] = {
    KryoSerializer
      .forAsync[IO](kryoRegistrar)
      .use { implicit kryo =>
          transaction.toBinary.liftTo[IO]
      }
  }

  def generateKryoBinary(): IO[Array[Byte]] =  {
    val transaction = new Transaction(Hash(""),"","","","","")
    val ioArray =  generateKryoBinaryIO(transaction);
    return ioArray
  }

}
```

I tried the below, but not working

```
 val i : Array[Byte] = for {
    array <- ioArray
  } yield array
```

Comment: Ideally you never ever extract a value outside of `IO` rather you create a new `IO` by transforming the previous one, using methods like `map` or `flatMap` - However, if you are not sold into using `IO` and just have this value from a third party library and you just want to continue writing your code as our used to do, you can call the `unsafeRunSync()` method to run the `IO` in that point and get its result.

Comment: FYI the for-comprehension you posted is syntax sugar for `ioArray.map(array => array)`, which is effectively a no-op.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just started working with cats-effect I recommend reading  about `cats.effect.IOApp` [which runs your IO](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/2.x/datatypes/ioapp).

Otherwise simple solutions would be:

1. run it explicitly and get the result:

```scala
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global

ioArray.unsafeRunSync()
```

2. or maybe work with `Future`:

```scala
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global

ioArray.unsafeToFuture()
```

Could you give us more context about your application ?

Comment: I edited my post. I am getting this error "No implicits found for parameter runtime : IORuntime"

Could not find an implicit IORuntime.

Comment: Yes you gotta use the mentioned import `cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global` to have an `IORuntime` available implicitly

Comment: It solved the issue